# Where does master.dacpac come from in VS 2019?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

We have some build tasks that run and for the life of me I can't figure out why the ms build tools isn't installing the master.dacpac file needed for the master and system dacpac files.

Here's where it lives now:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\150\SQLSchemas`

Currently, in VS2019 Professional it is added with the Data Storage and Processing Workload.  SQL Server Data Tools is a dependency for several other workloads, such as:

- ASP.NET and web development
- ASP.NET and web development tools
- Azure Data Lake and Stream Analytics Tools
- Cloud tools for web development

In MS Build Tools, I noticed that the dacpac file isn't generated after installing the Data Tools workload.

Am I looking in the wrong place?  What is generating the master.dacpac and the system.dacpac in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\Extensions\SqlServer\150\SQLSchemas`?

Comment: I don't think that this is a database administration related question - it's more of a programming one! Questions about tools round here are normally about administration, monitoring and such. Perhaps you'd be better asking on StackOverflow? p.s. welcome to the forum :-) and don't hesitate to come back if you have a (proper) database related question!

Comment: This question has to do with the infrastructure for working with database projects in visual studio.  This is still more suited to stack overflow?

Comment: Fair enough. I didn't VtC (vote to close) or anything like that. However, the question has been up for 15 hours and the only comment has been mine. I've added the `visual-studio` and `visual-studio-2019` tags so that anybody who filters on those will be able to see your post. If you've got nothing by Monday afternoon - say  16:00 UTC, I'd move it to StackOverflow. If you do that, be sure and put a link here to explain what you've done and a link in SO pointing back here - helps eliminate duplication of effort! Best of luck...

Comment: @rdelgado-incinc you'll probably get better traction if you delete this question here and post it on StackOverflow, even if it might be somewhat on topic for DBA.SE

Comment: I duplicated the post here, and someone from MSFT has responded.  Thank you for the suggestions.  I think the question is still relevant here, though, since this is more of an infrastructure question related to SQL, just in case someone is struggling to get build tools 2019 building projects that reference the default master.dacpac and system.dacpac files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58998783/where-does-master-dacpac-come-from-in-vs-2019